# C -Endless process in a function - Find the majority element with the " Divide and conquer " method

Tags: c, divide-and-conquer

as mentioned in the titled, my function doesn't end well. I am trying to do the following : 
" Implement, with the DC method, a function which has this interface :

- **Returns the majority element of the given sequence if one such exists**
- **PARAMETERS**
- sequence       Valid pointer to an array of elements
- sequenceLength Size of the array
  *
- **RETURN**
- element        A pointer to one element corresponding to the majority
- element or NULL if no such element exists

*const Element* getMajElDC(const Element* const * sequence, size_t sequenceLength); "

Actually, I just tried to implement this solution : http://www.ece.northwestern.edu/~dda902/336/hw4-sol.pdf

And here's my way to do it :

```
const Element* getMajElDC(const Element* const * sequence,    size_t,sequenceLength){
printf("1\n");

const Element* element_tmp_right;
const Element* element_tmp_left;
int occurence_left = 0;
int occurence_right = 0;


if (sequenceLength == 1)
    return sequence[1];

int mid = (int)sequenceLength/2;

element_tmp_left = getMajElDC(sequence,mid);

if (sequenceLength%2 == 0) 
    element_tmp_right = getMajElDC(&sequence[mid],mid);
element_tmp_right = getMajElDC(&sequence[mid],mid+1);


if (element_tmp_left == NULL && element_tmp_right != NULL)
    return element_tmp_right;
if (element_tmp_right == NULL && element_tmp_left != NULL)
    return element_tmp_left;


if (element_tmp_right == NULL && element_tmp_left == NULL)
    return NULL;




if (areEqual(element_tmp_left,element_tmp_right))
    return element_tmp_left;



for (int i=0;i<sequenceLength;i++){
    if( areEqual(sequence[i],element_tmp_left))
        occurence_left++;
    if (areEqual(sequence[i],element_tmp_right))
        occurence_right++;
}

if (occurence_left > mid+1)
    return element_tmp_left;
else if (occurence_left > mid+1)
    return element_tmp_left;
else
    return NULL;

}
```

When I try to run it in codeblocks, the .exe just stopworking. Just like if the function was endless. That's why I placed a printf in the beginning : I wanted to see how many times the " 1 " would appear in the application windows and it appears so many times that everything goes crazy.

I tried to look into the base case of the recursion, but nothing seems wrong with it...

I am truly lost my poor knowledge of C, does anyone see where the problem is ?

Ps : the areEqual() function is just a given function, here's its implementation but there is nothing special with it :

```
bool areEqual(const Element* a, const Element* b)
{
    return a->value == b->value;
}
```

with

```
struct element_t
{
    int value;
};

typedef struct element_t Element;
```

To end my question, I tell you in advance that I'm sorry if a crucial information is missing : It is the first time I use this website, please be indulgent !

Comment: It seems like you're not getting the recursion done properly, your ending condition never occurs. Try to step through the code in a debugger, line by line, stepping into the recursive calls, to see what really happens. It's probably going to be tedious and taker time, but it's still part of being a programmer so you need to learn it too.

Comment: I see a problem of not attempting to debug this code **step by step** (at least according to your detailed description).

Comment: I would like to add that it might be counter-productive to apologize in advance, users can see that you're new, and everyone should assume good will.

Answer (score 0):

You **have to use debugger** it will show you immediately where the problem is.
BTW look closer this code:

```
if (sequenceLength == 1)
    return sequence[1];

int mid = (int)sequenceLength/2;

element_tmp_left = getMajElDC(sequence,mid);

if (sequenceLength%2 == 0) 
    element_tmp_right = getMajElDC(&sequence[mid],mid);
element_tmp_right = getMajElDC(&sequence[mid],mid+1);
```

You close the recursion when `sequenceLength == 1`, but if `getMajElDC` has been called with `sequenceLength=0` it **will never return**.
Consider to modify:

```
if (sequenceLength == 1)
    return sequence[1];
```

to:

```
if (sequenceLength <= 1)
    return sequence[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

consider this code snippet:

```
int mid = (int)sequenceLength/2;

element_tmp_left = getMajElDC(sequence,mid);

if (sequenceLength%2 == 0) 
     element_tmp_right = getMajElDC(&sequence[mid],mid);
element_tmp_right = getMajElDC(&sequence[mid],mid+1);
```

notice that the third call to `getMajElDC` is always called regardless of the value of `sequenceLength`.  I suspect that you wanted to write this:

```
if (sequenceLength%2 == 0) 
     element_tmp_right = getMajElDC(&sequence[mid],mid);
else
     element_tmp_right = getMajElDC(&sequence[mid],mid+1);
```